# AuthenticateAsClient doesn't throw Exception when providing invalid Certificate

Tags: c#, authentication, tcpclient, tcplistener, sslstream

I created a Server based on a `TcpListener`. Incoming Connections are beeing handled parallelized using `ThreadPool`. The Communication occurs mutually authentificated using `SslStreams`.

Currently, when a Client with calls

```
var sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(),
                            false,
                            this.ServerCertificateValidation,
                            (a, b, collection, d, e) => collection[0]);

sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(Host, certCollection, protocols.Tls, false); // this does not throw an exception, even if the certCollection provides an invalid Certificate...
```

using an invalid Certificate (`collection[0]`) no exception is thrown and `sslStream.IsMutuallyAuthenticated`,  `sslStream.IsSigned` and `sslStream.IsEncrypted` all return `true`.

On the server-side calling

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(this.Certificate, true, SslProtocols.Tls, false);  // thows AuthentificationException as expected...
```

results in an `AuthentificationException`, just as expected.

How can I make the `AuthenticateAsClient`-call throw an Exception like it is expected, when the clients Certificate failed to validate on the server side. I would expect both Calls, `AuthenticateAsClient` and `AuthenticateAsServer` to throw the `AuthentificationException`, but it seems to only occur on the server. Or am i getting it wrong?

Maybe it has something to do with the parallelized Client-Processing by the server. I guess the Authentification is out of sync or sth., but i don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Is your IIS configured so that the Server requires client certificates? I think the default in SSL settings is to Accept, and not requires

Comment: I am not using IIS. Just `TcpListener` and `TcpClient`. The Server (`AuthentificateAsServer`) expects Clients to provide a Certificate (second Argument set to `true`) ValidationCallbacks are called btw.